# Apps for all Samsung Galaxy Tabs, how to make drawable and layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, galaxy-tab

I have **Galaxy tab 10.1 inch**  and I have made app and test on it, it works fine.

Now my question is will this app work on Galaxy  7 inch, Galaxy 7.7 inch, Galaxy note and Galaxy 8.9 inch

here is the details of these devices:

**(My Device) Galaxy tab 10.1 inch -->** 800 x 1280 pixels, 10.1 inches (~149 ppi pixel density)

**Galaxy 8.9 inch**--> 800 x 1280 pixels, 8.9 inches (~170 ppi pixel density)

**Galaxy 7.7 inch** --> 800 x 1280 pixels, 7.7 inches (~196 ppi pixel density)

**Galaxy  7 inch** --> 600 x 1024 pixels, 7.0 inches (~170 ppi pixel density)

**Galaxy Note** --> 800 x 1280 pixels, 5.3 inches (~285 ppi pixel density)

Please tell me for which device I have to make layouts again and what will be the folder names for drawable and layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer myself: In order to support maximum devices, we can try to make a general layout which fits for all device, there may be minor trade offs, but one can live with that. We can make such a layout by using Relative Layout as much as possible, if there comes a situation where you can not handle multiple device support, we can try handling it with code at run time, but in such a manner, that it runs on all device.

complete answer is here
[Layout for 720*1280 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660452/layout-for-7201280-devices/13660963#13660963)

Answer (score 2):

for Galaxy 7 inch --> 600 x 1024 pixels, 7.0 inches (~170 ppi pixel density) you can make layout folder with name "layout-large-mdpi-1024x600"....but for other device i am also unable to sort correct

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using relative layout mechanisms, it wil be ok. If you want to test it yourself, you can start your application in emulators using different screen sizes. There is also a Galaxy Tab Emulator.

Comment: how do I make emulator with 800 x 1280 pixels but different screen sizes

Comment: Start the SDK Manager -> Tools -> Manage AVD -> Create a new or Edit an existing -> Screen Resolution -> Select your desired one

Answer (score 1):

read 
[Multiple Screen Resolution Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)